# Jenkins doesn't include refrenced files when building conda package

Tags: python, linux, jenkins, conda

I am building a small conda package with Jenkins (linux) that should just:

- Download a .zip from an external refrence holding font files
- Extract the .zip
- Copy the font files to a specific folder
- Build the package

The build runs successful, but the package does not include the font files, but is basically empty. My build.sh has:

```
mkdir $PREFIX\root\share\fonts
cp *.* $PREFIX\root\share\fonts
```

My meta.yaml source has:

```
source:
url: <ftp server url>/next-fonts.zip
fn: next-fonts.zip
```

In Jenkins I do:

```
mkdir build
conda build fonts
```

The console output is strange though at this part:

```
+ mkdir /var/lib/jenkins/conda-bld/fonts_1478708638575/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_prootsharefonts
+ cp Lato-Black.ttf Lato-BlackItalic.ttf Lato-Bold.ttf Lato-BoldItalic.ttf Lato-Hairline.ttf Lato-HairlineItalic.ttf Lato-Italic.ttf Lato-Light.ttf Lato-LightItalic.ttf Lato-Regular.ttf MyriadPro-Black.otf MyriadPro-Bold.otf MyriadPro-Light.otf MyriadPro-Regular.otf MyriadPro-Semibold.otf conda_build.sh /var/lib/jenkins/conda-bld/fonts_1478708638575/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_prootsharefonts
BUILD START: fonts-1-1
Source cache directory is: /var/lib/jenkins/conda-bld/src_cache
Found source in cache: next-fonts.zip
Extracting download
Package: fonts-1-1
source tree in: /var/lib/jenkins/conda-bld/fonts_1478708638575/work/Fonts
number of files: 0
```

To me it seems the cp either doesn't complete or it copies to a wrong directory. Unfortunately, with the *placeholder* stuff I really can't decypher where exactly the fonts land when they are copied, all I know is that in /work/Fonts, there are no files and thus nothing is included in the package. While typing, I also noted that /work/Fonts actually has the Fonts starting with a capital F, while nowhere in the configuration or the scripts there is any instance of fonts starting with a capital F.

Any insight on what might go wrong?

Comment: Tried cp * instead of cp*.* in the build script and got the same behaviour.

Comment: Since I was using the build script from an already existing windows build script, the folder seperators were wrong. The job is running on a failure now with mkdir $PREFIX/root/share/fonts and cp * $PREFIX/root/share/fonts in the build script. I get an mkdir: cannot create directory, but that seems to be another story.

Comment: Change it to `mkdir -p $PREFIX/root/share/fonts` which will create all the intermediate directories

Comment: Thanks Eric! This works too of course. Lession learned: Don't re-use build scripts across operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir $PREFIX\root\share\fonts
cp *.* $PREFIX\root\share\fonts
```

should be replaced with

```
mkdir $PREFIX/root/share/fonts
cp * $PREFIX/root/share/fonts
```

The buildscript was taken from another package that was built in windows and in changing the build script I forgot to change the folder separators.

Additionally creating subfolder structures isn't possible in linux while it is in windows. So this

```
mkdir $PREFIX/root/
mkdir $PREFIX/root/share/
mkdir $PREFIX/root/share/fonts/
cp * $PREFIX/root/share/fonts/
```

Was the ultimate solution to the problem.